# Can the half-life of a free neutron be calculated or is it just empirical?

Tags: radiation, neutrons

Everyone keeps telling me its just 10.3 minutes and no one knows how to get that number form theory. Any idea?

Comment: See my answer to [Why is the (free) neutron lifetime so long?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31514/520).

Comment: @dmckee we should close as a dupe of your answer.