# Why do half lives of Carbon isotopes vary by a great extent?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, half-life

Both *Carbon-14* and *Carbon-15* decay by the $\beta^-$ mechanism but the half life for 
$C^{14}$ is approximately 5500 years whereas that if $C^{15}$ is around 2 seconds.What causes this disparity in half life time?

Comment: This is pretty common. As another example, half-life of carbon-12 is immeasurably long.

Comment: Yes, but the difference between C-14 and C-15 is just 1 neutron but the half lives vary greatly, I wanted to know what causes this huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radioactive decay occurs if there is an available state with lower energy than the current state of the nucleus.  For example, outside of a nucleus, neutrons decay into protons because protons are lighter (have lower mass-energy) than neutrons.

Inside a nucleus, however, neutrons can be stabilized by interactions with protons.  For example, a nucleus with many more protons than neutrons has a very high amount of electric charge concentrated in one place.  The electrostatic potential energy increases the total energy of the nucleus by an amount large enough to offset the proton-neutron mass difference.  Thus, the energy of the nucleus will be lower if a proton decays into a neutron, and the nucleus decays.

Nuclear physics is much more complex than this, and  a large imbalance between neutrons and protons is bad for nuclear stability for other reasons as well.  For example, a high density of neutrons means that neutrons are forced into high-energy states (for intuition on this, compare the particle in a box model). Also, neutrons repel each other via the strong force, as do protons, but neutrons and protons attract each other.  Since carbon-15 has a very large imbalance of neutrons and protons — 50% more neutrons than protons — we expect the energy difference $\Delta E$ from carbon-15 to nitrogen-15 to be large.

Beta decay proceeds via the weak interaction, so the rate is strongly dependent on the energy difference (see the answers to [Why is the (free) neutron lifetime so long?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/why-is-the-free-neutron-lifetime-so-long/31517#31517) for more information).  Thus, all other things being equal, if $\Delta E$ between two states is 2 MeV, the decay rate is much, much higher than it is for a $\Delta E$ of 1 MeV.

According to [the IAEA table of nuclides](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html), $\Delta E$ from carbon-15 to nitrogen-15 is 9873.1 keV - 101.4 keV = 9771.7 keV.  Thus, a lot of energy is available to power the decay and it proceeds quickly.  On the other hand, $\Delta E$ from carbon-14 to nitrogen-14 is only 3019.9 keV - 2863.4 keV = 157 keV, so decay proceeds slowly.