# Calculating neutron decay rate

Tags: neutrons

In [this](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=902353) paper, it is reported that the neutron decay rate is:

$$W=\dfrac{m_e^5c^4}{2\pi^3 \hbar^7}|\mathcal{M}| f$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the matrix element and $f$ is a factor space statistical factor and $m_e$ is the electron mass. The paper details the calculation of the matrix element, but does not explain how to calculate $f$ and the constant factor in front of the expression.

Can anyone suggest how to derive them or point out a reference that does?

Comment: I discuss the phase space calculation under https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/why-is-the-free-neutron-lifetime-so-long

Comment: http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ph611/2012/projects/Hayes.pdf