# The phase space suppression for 3 body decay

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

In particle physics, what does it mean the phase space suppression?

Comment: While I don't use the phrase "phase space suppression", I discuss the physics at work and the consequences in my answer to [Why is the (free) neutron lifetime so long?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31514/520)